# Advanced Menu 1.4.1 Menu Settings?

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS 1.4 with the Advanced Menu 1.4.1 module. When I enable the module and create a new menu and menu items, I do not see the menu displayed on my site. Also, I do not see a way to choose which menu is displayed if I create more than one menu. Where in the settings can I choose which menu is displayed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a Menu Widget to some zone (eg. the Navigation zone) in order to display a menu. When adding that widget you can choose which menu it should display.